# Mapping postgres function that returns table with Hibernate

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have searched all over stackoverflow and other sites but I cannot figure out how to map tables that are returned from postgres functions with Hibernate in a Spring application.

I am not even sure if the return type table from postgres function can be matched with MyCustomTable somehow.

What I am trying to do is to call postgres functions (stored procedures) from the spring app with hibernate.

I have this postgres function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func99(type text,start_date TIMESTAMP, end_date TIMESTAMP) RETURNS TABLE(
    some_day TIMESTAMP,
    tot_requests BIGINT)
 AS $$
 BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT t1.first_date, COUNT(*) FROM table1 t1
   WHERE t1.request_type = type and t1.first_date > start_date and t1.first_date < end_date;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/users/{username}/func99")
    public List<MyCustomTable> getResultsFromFunc99(@PathVariable(value = "username") String username,
                                                 @CurrentUser UserPrincipal currentUser,
                                                 @RequestParam(value = "service_type") String type,
                                                 @RequestParam(value = "start_date") Timestamp startDate,
                                                 @RequestParam(value = "end_date") Timestamp endDate){

        return queryService.getResultsFromFunc99(username, currentUser, type, startDate, endDate);
    }
```

Service

```
public List<MyCustomTable> getResultsFromFunc99(String username, UserPrincipal currentUser, String type, Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate) {

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "username", username));

      
        return return incidentRepository.func99(type, startDate, endDate);
```

Repository

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "func99")
    List<MyCustomTable> func99(String type, Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate);
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "func99",
        procedureName = "func99",
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "type", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "start_date", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Timestamp.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "end_date", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Timestamp.class)
        }
)
@Table(name = "table1")
public class MyCustomTable {...}
```

When a postgres function returns an integer i can make it work. What can i do to map table returns from postgres functions and how i integrate it with Hibernate?

Comment: The error I get is:Type cannot be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I use for a similar problem, but it might work.

Define a SqlResultSetMapping like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "MyCustomTableMapping",
    entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = MyCustomTable.class)
)
```

Then change this parameter to your `NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation:

```
resultSetMappings = "MyCustomTableMapping"
```

I use this technique with `NamedNativeQueries` to make sure Hibernate doesn't track them for changes like actual entities. Saves me and my colleagues from having to remember to `detach` lots of entities. Just about every tutorial on how to use search results that don't correspond to a table will leave you with that problem and treat it as okay.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution.

I don't use the method from repository.
Instead of the aforementioned repository:

```
*@Procedure(procedureName = "func99")
    List<MyCustomTable> func99(String type, Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate);*
```

I know do this inside service without using the repository:

```
@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
```

.

```
public List<MyCustomTable> getResultsFromFunc99(String username, UserPrincipal currentUser, String type, Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "username", username));

 Query query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("func99");
        query.setParameter("some_day", someDay);
        ((StoredProcedureQuery) query).execute();

return query.getResultList()
```

Entity class remains the same where i declare

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "func99",
        procedureName = "func99",
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "type", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "start_date", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Timestamp.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "end_date", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Timestamp.class)
        }
)
@Table(name = "table1")
public class MyCustomTable {...}
```